# Javascript google maps creating markers from xml data

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

-i have this code and I am testing it on Mozilla. This code should make large number of markes on map. I have my latitude and longitude for markers in XML file. When it run it it freeze the browser sor a few second and make only 15 markers. Console says this "too much recursion". I tried also use for(var i =0;i < x.length;i++) cycle but result was same except I didnt get "too much recursion" in console.

```
var map;
var i =0;
var xmldoc=loadXMLDoc("skoly.xml");
var x= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("skoly");
var image = {url: 'images/blackmarker.png',
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 10)};

function loop(){

 createMarker(function(){loop();});
 }

  function createMarker(callback) {
  var location =new google.maps.LatLng (xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("gps_latitude")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("gps_longitude")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map:map,
        icon: image
         });
         i++;
  if(i < x.length)callback();       
         }

function initialize() {
  var startlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.8037633,15.4749126,7);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: startlatlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions); 
  loop();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Code with for loop:

```
var map;
var xmldoc=loadXMLDoc("skoly.xml");
var x= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("skoly");
var image = {url: 'images/blackmarker.png',
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 10)};
  function createMarker(i) {
  var location =new google.maps.LatLng (xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("gps_latitude")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("gps_longitude")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map:map,
        icon: image
         });       
         }

function initialize() {
  var startlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.8037633,15.4749126,7);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: startlatlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);  
  for(var i =0;i < x.length;i++){createMarker(i);}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

XML file looks like :

```
  <DocumentElement>
    <skoly>
      <stuff1>someting</stuff1>
      <stuff2>something</stuff2>    
      <gps_latitude>49,2816216</gps_latitude>
      <gps_longitude>15,4402835</gps_longitude>
   </skoly>
   <skoly>
     .
     .
   </skoly>
</DocumentElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **loop()** and **createMarker()** functions are mutually recursive, which simply means that they call each other.

You can see this more clearly if we strip out the Google Maps code, simplify the loop() function, and rename the callback parameter:

```
function loop() {
  createMarker(loop);
} 

function createMarker(loop) {
  i++;
  if(i < x.length) loop();
}
```

**loop()** calls **createMarker()**, which in turn calls **loop()** – until it bottoms out at the end of the **x** collection.  The call stack size would be twice the length of x, which causes the "Too much recursion" error when the collection is large.

A **for** loop should work much better in this situation, but we'd need to see your **for** loop code (and possibly the XML file) to know why it fails.

Comment: That helps, thanks.  Change the commas to periods in your XML file's lat/long coordinates, and that should get you going.